# Flex/grid divide to keep the best item distribution

Tags: css

When we have a number of items and would like to arrange them in the lowest possible number of rows but when the number of rows grows then they should be distributed to make the smallest possible remaining space after last item.

For example: we have 11 equal width and height items and would like to show them in 1 row if there is enough space:

> [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11]

If there is not enough space for 11 columns then we like to show them in 2 rows with as small remaining space as possible, so 6 items in 1st row and 5 items in 2nd row:

> [1][2][3][4][5][6]

> [7][8][9][10][11]

And so with other arrangements:

> [1][2][3][4]

> [5][6][7][8]

> [9][10][11]

or:

> [1][2][3]

> [4][5][6]

> [7][8][9]

> [10][11]

Is there a way to make it as auto as possible (not to manually calculate all possible situations)? I've started with `minmax()` but I failed:
https://jsfiddle.net/dtwugzjx/1/

Comment: maybe you can solve it with a flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. You need javascript.